# Shell script: find maximum value in a sequence of integers without sorting

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file with a long list of integers:

```
10
4
66
....
```

I want to find the maximum value using UNIX command line tools.  I know I can use `sort` (and indeed there are solutions to this problem on SO that use `sort`), but that's inefficient, requiring  O(N*log(N)) and plenty of memory.  With a simple for loop, I should be able to find the maximum value in O(N) and a couple of bytes of memory.

It seems there must be some program out there (with a name like `max`) that does this out of the box---is that true?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use this if no negative number is expected:

```
awk '$0>x{x=$0};END{print x}' input.txt
```

Use this to support negative numbers:

```
awk 'BEGIN{x=-2147483648};$0>x{x=$0};END{print x}' input.txt
```

Initializing `x` allows the solution to properly handle integer lists with values <= 0. See the comments for more details.

Comment: Good one! Note the `;` before `END` is not needed.

Comment: One place where this fails. If you list of integers has only one value and that value is 0. Your output ends up blank. Actually. If you have any single value list where the value is <=0 it is blank. So, negatives won't work either it appears. Actually...negatives don't work at all with this (single value or not).

Comment: Upon further investigation, this fails if the only values in your list are <= 0 since you don't initialize x. You can resolve that with `awk 'BEGIN{x=<<MIN_INT>>};$0>x{x=$0};END{print x}'` where <<MIN_INT>> is some really negative number. E.g., `awk 'BEGIN{x=-2147483648};$0>x{x=$0};END{print x}'` assuming an awk version compiled with 32-bit values for variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
 max=1

 while read i
 do
  if [[ "$i" > "$max" ]]; then
     max="$i"
  fi
 done < a.txt

 echo "$max" > b.txt
```

a.txt is the input file(with an integer on each line).
b.txt contains the maximum of the integers in a.txt.

Comment: `>` and `<` are for lexical sorting within tests. Use `(())` or `let` in shells that support them, or `[ n -gt m ]` for POSIX scripts. Also, always use `read -r`. Also, you probably meant to `max=$i`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if($1>a)a=$1;}END{print a}' temp3
```

Answer (score 0):

sort -nr inputfile.txt | head -1 
where inputfile.txt contains all numbers.