# Getting max version by file name

Tags: shell, awk, grep, sh

I need to write a shell script that does the following:

1. In a given folder with files that fit the pattern: `update-8.1.0-v46.sql` I need to find the maximum version
2. I need to write the maximum version I've found into a configuration file

For 1, I've found the following answer: [Shell script: find maximum value in a sequence of integers without sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931676/shell-script-find-maximum-value-in-a-sequence-of-integers-without-sorting)
The only problem I have is that I can't get down to a list of only the versions,
I tried:

```
ls | grep -o "update-8.1.0-v\(\d*\).sql"
```

but I get the entire file name in return and not just the matching part
Any ideas?
Maybe move everything to `awk`?

I ended up using:

```
SCHEMA=`ls database/targets/oracle/ | grep -o "update-$VERSION-v.*.sql" | sed "s/update-$VERSION-v\([0-9]*\).sql/\1/p" | awk '$0>x{x=$0};END{print x}'`
```

based on dreamer's answer

Comment: `sort -V` may be simpler than parsing the max version integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `sed` for this:

```
echo "update-8.1.0-v46.sql" | sed 's/update-8.1.0-v\([0-9]*\).sql/\1/p'
```

The output in this case will be `46`

Answer (score 0):

`grep` isn't really the best tool for extracting captured matches, but you can use look-behind assertions if you switch it to use perl-like regular expressions. Anything in the assertion will not be printed when using the `-o` flag.

```
ls | grep -Po "(?<=update-8.1.0-v)\d+"
46
```